# Filter data using daterangepicker angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using [**ng-bs-daterangepicker**](http://github.com/luisfarzati/ng-bs-daterangepicker) and I'm having trouble filter when I select `start date` and `end date`.

Here's a piece of my `code`:

```
<input type="daterange" ng-model="dates" ranges="ranges">
<tr ng-repeat="item in items">
    <td>{{created_date|date:'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</td>
</tr>
```

My `JSON` data:

```
[
    {
        "created_date": 1469017951592
    },
    {
        "created_date": 1469017951592
    },
    {
        "created_date": 1469017951592
    },
    {
        "created_date": 1469017951592
    }
]
```

Comment: You should post at least the link of the module that you're using.

Comment: I am using https://github.com/luisfarzati/ng-bs-daterangepicker for datepicker

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation in [ng-bs-datepicker](https://github.com/luisfarzati/ng-bs-daterangepicker), you can put the min-date and max-date attributes.

```
<input
    type="daterange"
    ng-model="dates"
    min-date="2013-09-10"
    max-date="2013-09-25">
```

You can also choose a special range that takes an object having with 'Special Range' key and another object with startDate and endDate as value:

```
"{'Special Range':{'startDate': '2013-09-2', 'endDate': '2013-09-5'}}"
```

Additionally, you can use the two links below for demo:

1. https://github.com/luisfarzati/ng-bs-daterangepicker/blob/master/example/index.html
2. http://luisfarzati.github.io/ng-bs-daterangepicker/